# Using th sqlite legacy_file_format on Android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I wonder where one would call `db.execSQL ("PRAGMA legacy_file_format=OFF;");`on Android.

I see a chicken / egg problem here as `legacy_file_format=OFF` only take effect when the next db is created. But then you need a db object to call `execSQL`.